# MassTransit with RabbitMQ: messages deduplication

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, masstransit

I am using `MassTransit` with `RabbitMQ` at transport layer, and faced the need of messages deduplication.

Adding new massage to the queue should be skipped if duplicated message already queued (even if that message is processing by consumer). Duplicates could be identified by content of message for example.

Sending `DoWork1, DoWork2, DoWork3` could be processed in parallel, but sending `DoWork1, DoWork2, DoWork2` - duplicate should be skipped, and as far as `DoWork1, DoWork2` processed same messages could be enqueued and should not be supposed as duplicates.

Solution 1: use "[RabbitMQ Message Deduplication Plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication#exchange-level-deduplication)" at the exchange layer, ideal as for me, but not sure that solves described problem.

Solution 2: implement custom middleware with third party data storage.

Is there any better solution for described problem?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: How are the duplicates being generated?

Comment: For example when publisher sends several same messages

Comment: These aren't "same messages" then since they have different message ids

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev technically, they aren't, logically, they are. interested in how to solve something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [RabbitMQ deduplication plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) was designed for that purpose.

You can either de-duplicate at the exchange or at the queue. The main difference is the exchange de-duplicates a message if it has seen it previously while the queue de-duplicates it if already contains a copy of it.

When publishing a message, just set the `x-deduplication-header` header with a string which uniquely identifies a message (for example the MD5 hash of its body).

Using custom middleware will allow you more freedom of action at the cost of your own development.

Comment: I've tried to use the above plugin, also with MassTransit, but cannot get it to work at the queue level without turning off PublisherConfirmation. If PublisherConfirmation is on then the Send operation just hangs when it strikes a duplicate. It looks like this was a known issue (https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/issues/21) but still doesn't seem to be working. Are other people having a similar problem?

Comment: https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/issues/67#issuecomment-782827895